# Take data from socket connection and split it

Tags: python

This is from a homework question but I'm not too familiar with Python and couldn't find any information on what is going on in the statements below.

```
 message = connectionSocket.recvfrom(1024)
 filename = message.split()[1] 
 f = open(filename[1:])
```

So, message is just taking the data from the client connected to connectionSocket and putting it in message. From there I can tell that the message is split which means its taking the string in message and returning a list of words (which I'm guessing the delimiter is just a space). But what is that [1]?

It's supposed to be a webserver so I'm thinking of a scenario such as if I go to serverAddress:serverPort/HelloWorld.html the message is the 'HelloWorld.html" part, right? and then I am opening the file. But I'm lost on the purpose of [1] and [1:].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename = message.split()[1]
```

You guessed (correctly) that the string in `message` is split and returned as a list of words.

If this is a HTTP request, then the first 1024 bytes of `message` will be something like:

`"GET /file.html cruft..."` or `"GET /path/file.html cruft..."`.

By `split`ting this string you generate a list beginning:

`["GET", "/file.html", "cruft..."]`.

The [1] denotes the element indexed [1] within the list, i.e. the second element, the first index position being [0]. So `filename` = `"/file.html"` or = `"/directory/subdirectory/file.html"`

---

```
f = open(filename[1:])
```

This slices whatever is in `filename`, again using the indices. [1:] returns every element of `filename` from [1] to the end. If the assumptions above are right, then it'll discard the leading `/` and allow the file to be opened.

Comment: As an example what would be at index 0? Am I correct in thinking that it is parsing HelloWorld.html as the full message so f = open(HelloWord.html)?

Comment: I've made an educated guess as to what is going on and improved the answer based on that assumption.

Comment: URLs use forward slashes (`/`), not backslashes (`\\`).